# Can SE cable run from service drop inside the building, out to meter, and then to disconnect

Tags: electrical

Lateral drop connects to home, then runs down the inside wall to the meter (outside).  Is this legal?

[image]

Comment: Your location matters.  If local power company and government says it is okay, not much you can do.  Might not like it.

Comment: Who's your electric utility?